# Different forms of initialization

Tags: c++

I was reading this book called 'A Tour of C++' by Bjarne Stroustrup and inside it is mentioned that there are basically two ways of initialization:

> int a = 5.2; // Stores truncated value
>
> int a{5.2}; // Compiler throws error

As you can see, the latter method is safer and recommended.

However, I have noticed that:

> int a(5.2);

also works (and unlike the second version, it doesn't check if the type matches).

So, can someone please explain the third case, I mean, when it should be used and how it's different than the first case.

Comment: If it's saying two kinds, it probably means direct-initialization vs. copy-initialization. Both the second and your other way are direct-initialization. That's not to say they have the same semantics, though.

Comment: One reason for using the curly braces notation is that it avoids "the most vexing parse", where an intended variable declaration is interpreted as a function declaration. And indeed that's generally safer. One reason for using the C++03 round parentheses notation is that it can't give you list initialization by mistake, and that it's not so fuzzy about allegedly "narrowing" conversions, in particular for enumerations.

Comment: The idea behind the error is that `int a = 5.2;` is a pretty fishy thing to want to write in the first place, it's more likely to be a typo than a genuine intent.

Comment: BTW there's a fourth way, `int a = { 5.2 };`

Comment: If you replace int with a class, then `T a(5.2);` calls a constructor and `T a = 5.2;` calls the *same* constructor implicitly (doesn't work if constructor marked `explicit`).

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes, but the book said that the  '=' operator would be redundant in that case and it essentially becomes the second case again.

Answer (score 5):

When you use int a(5.2); you are calling the constructor of int, which is a C++ method to initialize variables. 
This is equivalent to others.
According to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/ :

> In C++, there are three ways to initialize variables. They are all
>   equivalent and are reminiscent of the evolution of the language over
>   the years:
>
> The first one, known as c-like initialization (because it is inherited
>   from the C language), consists of appending an equal sign followed by
>   the value to which the variable is initialized:
>
> type identifier = initial_value; For example, to declare a variable of
>   type int called x and initialize it to a value of zero from the same
>   moment it is declared, we can write:
>
> ```
> int x = 0;
> ```
>
> A second method, known as constructor initialization (introduced by
>   the C++ language), encloses the initial value between parentheses
>   (()):
>
> type identifier (initial_value); For example:
>
> ```
> int x (0);
> ```
>
> Finally, a third method, known as uniform initialization, similar to
>   the above, but using curly braces ({}) instead of parentheses (this
>   was introduced by the revision of the C++ standard, in 2011):
>
> type identifier {initial_value}; For example:
>
> ```
> int x {0};
> ```