# Variable initialization guidelines in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Which are the guidelines to initialize  variables in C++? There are so many ways to initialize a variable in C++. 3 ways with which I am familiar are as following:

> 1) int a=3;
>
> 2) int a(3);
>
> 3) int a{3};                // valid for C++11 & later

Which is the best approach? Why 2nd way int a(3); is not seen so often & not used in C++ programs?
Thanks.

Comment: This is quite opinion based. How do you define "best"? Do you only care about ints, or classes and structs also? It's quite different.

Comment: Also might be more on-topic at Programmers, since it's not a specific code problem.

Comment: The second alternative is hard to read, and actually equally hard for the compiler. Is `a` a function or a variable? Related reading: [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). In this case it works as intended, but be careful with that syntax.

Comment: Don't forget about `int a = {3};`, and 
`int a = int(3);` `auto a = 3;` (and all other variants)

Comment: See this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29068684/335858

Comment: @meet It was already mentioned why your question is off-topic, so why do you wonder about close and down votes?

Comment: @meet yep, you can even do `int a = int();`

Comment: @WesleyShillingford _"you can even do `int a();`"_ Read Joachim's comment and the link thoroughly.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Yes that was a mistake, I have modified it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two initializations have exactly the same effect. I would guess that most people prefer the first option over the second one because it looks more natural.

The third option however has different rules: It forbids narrowing conversion. So while you can do

```
int a = .3;
```

and get an `int` that equals zero,

```
int a {.3};
```

will be a compile time error. So the brace initializer has the advantage that it stops you from doing such conversions on accident and forces you explicitly state you intend if you *really* want a narrowing conversion.

Comment: Well the brace initializer *is* a C++11 feature, so if you write for a pre-C++11 compiler, you cannot use it. (Not sure if I understood your comment) Btw, your compiler might be able to warn you about narrowing conversion even when compiling pre-C++11 code.

Comment: @meet As I wrote, there is no difference between the alternatives. You can just use whatever "looks prettier", and what that is is subject to opinion, something we don't argue about on SO.